# NameError: name 'recursiveFunction' is not defined

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    print(longestPalindrome("abc"))

    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        (left, right) = longestPalindromeHelp(0, s.length - 1, s, {})
        return s[left:right + 1]

    def longestPalindromeHelp(left, right, s, dict):
        if left >= right:
            dict[(left, right)] = (left, right)
            return (left, right)

        if s[left] != s[right]:  # reverse all possible substring
            (a, b) = dict[(left + 1, right)] if (left + 1,
                                                 right) in dict else longestPalindromeHelp(left + 1, right, s, dict)
            (c, d) = dict[(left, right - 1)] if (left, right -
                                                 1) in dict else longestPalindromeHelp(left, right - 1, s, dict)
            return (a, b) if b - a > d - c else (c, d)
        else:  # current first and last are the same
            (a, b) = dict[(left + 1, right - 1)] if (left + 1, right -
                                                     1) in dict else longestPalindromeHelp(left + 1, right - 1, s, dict)
            return (left, right) if left + 1 == a and right - 1 == b else (a, b)
```

When I run it I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    class Solution:
  File "test.py", line 3, in Solution
    print(longestPalindrome("abc"))
NameError: name 'longestPalindrome' is not defined
```

I'm pretty new to python have no idea why `longestPalindrome` is considered `not defined`. I've tried switching the order of the functions and I have sometimes gotten the error the `longestPalindromeHelp` is not defined. I have also gotten indentation errors, but I've went around and made sure there's no spaces mixed with tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `print(longestPalindrome("abc"))` outside, and after the class. Same indentation level as `class`

```
s = Solution()
print(s.longestPalindrome("abc"))
```

Also, you're missing `self` in the second method

You cannot call an instance method without an instance

You don't even need a class here, and please don't name a variable `dict`, as that overrides the builtin Python function of the same name

Comment: I still get the same error except this time it's `longestPalindromeHelp` not defined. The trace starts from `(left, right) = longestPalindromeHelp(0, s.length - 1, s, {})` this time

Comment: You need `self.longestPalindromeHelp()`, but again, you do not need a class